# Does invokestatic put the return value on the stack when the method has a return value?

Tags: java, jvm

I have reading [JVM documetion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) about `invokevirtual`.

I have see it will pop the entry form stack, and then no one push into stack.

```
Operand Stack
    ..., objectref, [arg1, [arg2 ...]] →

    ...
```

Is this only true if you call a method that has no return value?

————————————————————————————————

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello JVM!");
        Integer integer = 1;
    }
```

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: ldc           #3                  // String Hello JVM!
         5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: iconst_1
         9: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        12: astore_1
        13: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 6: 0
        line 7: 8
        line 8: 13
```

In the code above：

8: `iconst_1` push the `int` into stack

9: `invokestatic` pop the `int` form stack  // stack is empty now

12: `astore_1`

Does invokestatic put the return value on the stack when the method has a return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically not, but effectively yes.

`invokestatic` only pushed the return value on the operand stack if the invoked method is `native` (which in this case confusingly means non-Java code).

For non-native methods (i.e. all "normal" methods written in Java) that job is done by the `*return` opcodes, which will be the last instruction executed (assuming normal termination of the method). For example [`areturn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.areturn):

> If no exception is thrown, objectref is popped from the operand stack of the current frame [...] and pushed onto the operand stack of the frame of the invoker.

Since regular returns only happen via the `*return` opcodes a successful `invokestatic` of a non-void method is guaranteed to have the return value popped onto the operand stack.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Totally solved it!
Regarding the description of the invokevirtual instruction, I was very surprised that there was no stacking operation.
It turns out that *return performs this stacking (across frames)

Comment: I guess they chose this way because otherwise there would need to exist some "intermediate space" where the return value is stored by `*return` until it's pushed onto the stack by `invokestatic`. The designers probably felt that pushing onto the callers operand stack in `*return` is the less messy solution that doesn't require inventing an additional place to store values.